# Get list of changed files in svn in Excel Sheet

Tags: svn

I Want to get a list of all changed files in svn first revision to last, I want to all changed file in excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSV file with your favorite svn client and open it in Excel.
Excel reads CSV so that you don't really need to know internal excel format.

Comment: Could you pls give me a command which provide me a list of all files modified/added between of first to last revision with options of CSV. Thanks.

Comment: There are no options for CSV, you'll need to fiddle a little with parsing. Basically for you can use svn diff like this: svn diff -r REVNO:HEAD --summarize

Answer (score 0):

You can run a svn diff and output to an xml file.  Then run this basic xsl file against it.

Put this in a .bat file

```
set __SVNClient="C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe"
set __svnBaseSVNSourceLocation=https://mySVNServer.com/MyRepository

%__SVNClient% diff --revision 333:HEAD "%__svnBaseSVNSourceLocation%"  --summarize --username %USERNAME% --xml >>svndiffexample.xml

set __svnBaseSVNSourceLocation=
set __SVNClient=
```

Then apply this xsl to the above xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">item,props,kind,path<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="//diff/paths/path">
<xsl:value-of select="@item"/>,<xsl:value-of select="@props"/>,<xsl:value-of select="@kind"/>,<xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and you'll get an output like this

```
item,props,kind,path
modified,none,file,https://mySVNServer.com/MyRepository/MyFile01.txt
modified,none,file,https://mySVNServer.com/MyRepository/ABCFolder/INC/MyFile01.inc
modified,none,file,https://mySVNServer.com/MyRepository/ABCFolder/Js/MyFile01.js
modified,none,file,https://mySVNServer.com/MyRepository/DEFFolder/MyFile01.pdf
```